# Can't get property value in Jmeter master-slave mode

Tags: jmeter, master-slave

I wrote a jmeter plugin which is used to analyze jmeter sample event, and send the results to a specified server. In this plugin, user can config the server IP/Port etc. These configurations normally use the variable and read them from given CSV file(using CSV config plugin). For example, the variables could be filled like: **${serverIP}, ${serverPort}** on plugin GUI.

Ok, my jmx and plugin with these configurations can work well in single mode. But now, I have requirement to run them in Master-Slave mode, the problem is coming, the **${serverIP}, ${serverPort}** can't not be converted to real value in **Master** side. I added some logs in my plugin codes which I used Jemter API to read its value

`public String getServerIP() {
    return getPropertyAsString(SERVER_IP);
}`

and found jmeter straightly return me with the variable name: **${serverIP}**, not like what it did in single mode that convert them to real value.

I googled and searched Jmeter doc, but nothing found, How could I let jmeter read configured variable from given CSV file in **Master** side(I know it could do this in Slave side). Can't Jmeter support it?

Any help are really appreciated! If you need more infos, please let me know, Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the OS? Linux or windows?

Comment: @user7294900 is linux